# wxPython program - render HTML

Tags: python, wxpython

Is it possible to render HTML in a Python window, using wxPython as the GUI builder.

For example, I give a program the URL http://google.com and then it loads up that domain name and renders it in a window below, but still in the confines of the Python program.

```
|---------------------------------------|
| URL: google.com                       |
|---------------------------------------|
|                                       |
|      VIEW THAT RENDERS WEBPAGE        |
|           OF GOOGLE.COM               |
|                                       |
|---------------------------------------|
```

I'm thinking that I need something like this: [How can I render JavaScript HTML to HTML in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29404856/how-can-i-render-javascript-html-to-html-in-python)

But rendering it in the wxPython window, and not loading up Firefox.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it is simpler to check the [wxPython demo](https://www.wxpython.org/download.php). It contains two applied examples (search for html), one simple renderer (no CSS) and an advanced one which uses the rendering engine of the underlying platform to display HTML.